# Why doesn't my upgradeble contract upgrade properly?

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, goerli

I have an upgradeable contract, but when I upgrade it, it doesn't go to the same address.

After I deploy the upgrade, the console shows TransparentUpgradeableProxy getting a new address, but that address does not have the functionality added in the upgraded contract nor the same tokens already created in the new contract. It does, however, have the functionality of the old contract.

Below are my deployment scripts:

`1_deploy_upgradeable_Placeholder.js`

```js
const { deployProxy } = require('@openzeppelin/truffle-upgrades');

const Placeholder = artifacts.require('Placeholder');

module.exports = async function (deployer) {
  const instance = await deployProxy(Placeholder, { deployer });
  console.log('Deployed', instance.address);
};
```

and:

`//2_upgrade_AlmaNFT.js`

```js
const { upgradeProxy } = require('@openzeppelin/truffle-upgrades');

const Placeholder = artifacts.require('Placeholder');
const Placeholderv2 = artifacts.require('Placeholderv2');

module.exports = async function (deployer) {
  const existing = await Placeholder.deployed();
  await upgradeProxy(existing.address, Placeholderv2, { deployer });
};
```

I interact with them through the truffle console, and use

```js
const place = Placeholder.at(TransparentUpgradeableProxy address)
```

after which I perform functions like so:

```js
place.function()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get an error here? Or what is happening?

Comment: When I deploy the upgraded contract, the proxy doesn't perform the functions of the upgraded contract

Comment: Try interacting with the original address? A new proxy just contains new logic to use, nothing should actually be used at the address of the newly deployed functionality. Also I'm a little confused since this is all spread across multiple files and control flows, especially the ```const place = Placeholder.at(TransparentUpgradeableProxy address)```

Comment: I tried the original address, it still works, just without the upgrade

Answer (score 0):

It actually works fine, I just needed to interact by writing:

```
const place = await Placeholderv2.at(TransparentUpgradeableProxy address)
```